# How to read nested json array value from lua table

Tags: lua

How can  we get the value the nestedarray value from lua table

This is my sample request body
"request" {
"name":"abcd",
"pincode":"1223444"
}

"PhoneNumbers" [
{
"Type":"home",
"Number":"1234456"
},
{
"Type:"personal",

"Number":"66666666"}

]

If I want the value of home then I can  get the value by doing like this phoneNumber[1].type

But in real scenario I need to get the value dynamically from the lua table

This is my code
local payloadValue = cjon.decode(requetpaylpad)

So if I want home type value, i can write like below
local value=payloadValue.phoneNumber[1].type

But I need to get the value dynamically using loop based the nested array which we are passing as a string

Can someone please help me to read the values of nested arrays

Comment: What does "dynamically" mean?

Comment: Which means, The nested array element will be given in UI by user, Suppose if user will give phoneNumber[1].type or sometimes phoneNumber [2].number.    Beased on the user input we need to get value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load) function to execute a string.

```
local userInput = 'phoneNumber[2].number'
local chunk = 'return (...).' .. userInput
local value = load(chunk)(payloadValue)
```